# how to set div height as background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is that the height of the DIV will change depending on the image size (without repeat)
I'm looking for a solution with broad browser support,I have already tried almost every answer I found on Google, nothing really worked

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#div_1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/YRwty0q/11.jpg");
}
#div_2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/khjZcj2/222.jpg");
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_2"></div>
<script>
  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just use an `<img>` tag instead?

Comment: @Reyno I know it's more recommended but it would have required me to change a lot of existing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the image with Javascript:

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  const url = getComputedStyle(this)['background-image'].slice(5, -2)
  const img = new Image()
  img.src = url
  img.onload = () => {
    $(this).css({
      width: img.width,
      height: img.height
    })
  }
})
```

```css
#div_1 {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/YRwty0q/11.jpg");
}

#div_2 {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/khjZcj2/222.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_2"></div>
```

Comment: @postFix The whole jQuery for a simple task is a bit overkill. I would try to implement a vanilla JS solution

Answer (score 0):

Set the `background-image` property with the URL of the image as its value for the `<div>` element.

Set the `background-repeat` property of the the `<div>` element to `no-repeat` so as not to repeat the image.

Set the `visibility` to `hidden` for the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).